# Embeddable is creating 2 tables jpa springs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have  below entites

AbstractOrderEntry :

```
@Getter @Setter
public class AbstractOrderEntry implements Serializable  
 {
@ElementCollection
private List<DiscountValue> discountValues = new ArrayList<>();}
}
```

CartEntry extending AbstractOrderEntry

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(value = AuditListener.class)
@Table(name = "cartentry")
@Getter @Setter
 public class CartEntry extends AbstractOrderEntry implements Serializable,Cloneable,Auditable
{
 @Id
@Column(name="CartEntryID",nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
 }
```

DiscountValueEntity:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter @Setter
public class DiscountValue {
private  String code;
private  BigDecimal value;
private  BigDecimal appliedValue;
 }
```

When I start the server it is generating to tables like

```
cart_discountValue
cart_discountvalue
```

one with camelcase and other is with lowercase.
We are also extending AbstractOrderEntry  for order entity as well hence for order also 2 tables are getting created.

How can overcome this issue.Because of this issue table data is not properly persisting.
Thanks , Inadvance.
Sree

Comment: 1. It is confusing/why `AbstractXXXClass` is not `abstract` ...2. why not "mapped" or "entity"? (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html)

Comment: Agree.it was implemented by someone else and it is in support now.Can't go back and modified the class